# Every graph G containing a cycle satisfies g(G)≤2d+1.

Tags: graph-theory

Proof: Let C be a shortest cycle in G. If g(G)≥ 2diam(G) + 2, then C has two vertices whose distance in C is at least diam(G)+1.

*Question: why is it at least diam(G)+1?*

cont. of proof: In G, these vertices have a lesser distance; any shortest path P between them is therefore not a subgraph of C.

*how i understood: A path "around" the cycle creates a longer path than the shortest path between x and y in G. Therefore, this shortest path P is not a subgraph of the shortest cycle C.*

rest of the proof: Thus, P contains a C-path xPy. Together with the shorter of the two x-y paths in C, this path xPy forms a shorter cycle than C, a contradiction.

*Question: why does P contain a C-path xPy if it is not a subgraph of C?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of $C$ is $\ge 2 \operatorname{diam}(G)+2$, so if you choose two opposite vertices, the shortest path between then (in $C$) is half the length of the cycle which is $\ge \operatorname{diam}(G)+1$.

Your understanding of why the shortest path $P$ is not a subgraph of $C$ is correct.

For the rest of the proof, you should delete the sentence "$P$ contains a $C$-path $xPy$." Just join the path $P$ with one of the $x$-$y$ paths in $C$ to obtain a smaller cycle.

Comment: ahh i understand now! thank you! :)

Comment: Please sorry but can I ask you question on this topic. I do agree that in $G$ these vertices have a lesser distance. But this is true if such path between those points exist. What is such path does not exist at all?

Comment: @ZFR This is due to the definition of $\text{diam}(G)$: the distance between any two vertices of $G$ is $\le \text{diam}(G)$ which must be smaller than $\text{diam}(G)+1$.

Comment: I guess you did not get my question. I'll try to give more details. Suppose that $g\geq 2d+2$ and $C$ be a shortest cycle in $G$. Then we can find two vertices $x,y$ in $C$ such that $d_C(x,y)=d+1$, right? Then by definition of diameter $d_G(x,y)\leq \text{diam}(G)=d<d+1=d_C(x,y)$, i.e. $d_G(x,y)<d_C(x,y)$. But I am saying if $G$ is itself cycle then this inequality obviously not true. So I guess something is missing in this reasoning. Is it clear right now what I am asking?

Comment: @ZFR The proof begins with the assumption that the smallest cycle has length $\ge 2 \text{diam}(G) + 2$, in order to derive a contradiction. As you point out, if $G=C$, then this assumption doesn't hold, since the cycle has length $\le 2 \text{diam}(G)$. But this case is not relevant for the proof: we only want to show that the "bad" cases (where the smallest cycle has length $\ge 2 \text{diam}(G) + 2$) cannot happen.

Comment: I am still confused. I guess we need to consider separate cases when $G$ is a cycle or not. I cannot even formulate my question in a wrong. But this theorem indeed has a subtle moment which we need to take care of.

Comment: Because $d_G(x,y)<d_C(x,y)$ is not true in general. I am very confused :(

Comment: @ZFR I think you are just confused about the proof by contradiction. The scenario in the proof will *not* be true for *any* graph $G$, not just cases where $G$ is a cycle. (The case where $G$ is a cycle is not a special case here.) This is because we are doing a proof by contradiction: we are purposely considering an impossible scenario that no graph satisfies, in order to derive a contradiction.

Comment: I have spent some time trying to grasp what you meant and here is my understanding: So we assume that there is some specific graph $G$ for which $g\geq 2d+2$. Suppose $C$ is a shortest cycle in $G$ then we can find two vertices $u,v\in C$ such that $d_C(u,v)=d+1$. Since there is at least one path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$ then from definition of diameter it follows that $d_G(x,y)<d+1$. Hence there is path $P$ in $G$ from $u$ to $v$ such that its length is $t\leq d$. Then joining $P$ with the smallest path from from $u$ to $v$ along $C$ we obtain a cycle of length $t+d+1\leq 2d+1$. Contradiction.

Comment: Is my understanding correct? :)

Comment: @ZFR Yes, that's right